# How to use User Input in Recursion Java

Tags: java, recursion, user-input

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner play = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter price of shoe 1: ");
    int n = play.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter price of shoe 2: ");     
    int m = play.nextInt();
    calculateShoe(int n, int m);
    
}
public static int calculateShoe(int n, int m) {
    if(n < m) {
        System.out.println("Shoe 1 is less than shoe 2.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Your total is: " + n + " and your savings are: " + m);
    }
        
    
}
```

}

The only error I get in this program is calling back the recursion method. I do not know how to call the program back using user input.

Comment: Printing some info about 2 entered shoe sizes is fundamentally not a recursive job. I think you mean something else with that word compared to what it tends to mean in programming parlance. Thus, what do you mean? Do you mean, perhaps: How can I keep asking the user for 2 shoes over and over?

Comment: `calculateShoe(int n, int m);  --->  calculateShoe(n, m);`

Comment: 1. Note that "recursion" is a very well defined concept that your whole code has absolutely nothing to do with. 2. When passing parameters to methods you don't need to redefine the variable type. just do `calculateShoe(n, m);` This is by the way covered in every beginenrs java tutorial like [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not be calling `calculateShoe(int n, int m)`. It should be just `calculateShoe(n, m);`
2. Also the return type of `calculateShoe` should be `void` and not `int`.
3. Close the scanner object `play.close();`

And the code you have posted has nothing to do with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RecursionDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner play = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter price of shoe 1: ");
        int n = play.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter price of shoe 2: ");     
        int m = play.nextInt();
        int choice;
        
        calculateShoe(n, m);
        
        do {
            System.out.print("Press 1 for exit :  ");
            choice = play.nextInt();
            
            if(choice > 0 && choice != 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter price of shoe 1: ");
                int n1 = play.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter price of shoe 2: ");     
                int m1 = play.nextInt();
                calculateShoe(n1, m1);
            }    
        } while(choice!=1);   
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You are exited from program...");
    }
    public static int calculateShoe(int n, int m) {
        if(n < m) {
            System.out.println("Shoe 1 is less than shoe 2.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Your total is: " + n + " and your savings are: " + m);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```